# Why killing/death is more accepted (morally) than nudity on television/movies?

Tags: logic, ethics

Is there any logic why killing/death is more accepted (morally) on television rather than nudity/sex?

It seems like a paradox to me the fact that all the laws (in the Occident) have severe punishment to 'killing' and are tolerant to 'nudity or body exposition contraventions', but in the television/movies the same topics are treated in an opposite way.

Is there any logic thought to explain this behavior?

Comment: This seems culture-specific.  America, in particular, seems much more uptight about sex and nudity than violence.  It doesn't make particular sense to me either.

Comment: I was searching for some example and found this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eO1VvWAVg9Q
I mean, Disney would never show the characters naked. So, why to show them dying? That's my point.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a specific culture, not about ethics or, as the tag suggests, logic.

Comment: @iphigenie agreed it is not to do with logic, but is it not a reasonable philosophical question about morals? Why not try to improve it instead of closing it?

Comment: I agree that I've failed to classify the question, I'm sorry. Feel free to re-tag it. But, this is a thing that really bothers me. Why the code of conduct (law?) of certain country/people punish a certain behavior, but the same behavior is widely accepted in a movie/tv?
Don't get me wrong, I'm asking for a direction on this in a humble way. (Sorry if my English suggests something different)

Comment: Is there any chance you could share a little more about what you might be reading that may have made this an interesting or important problem in your study of *philosophy*? What hypotheses have you formed and what has your research uncovered? What exactly does an an answer to this question look like in your mind?

Comment: Hmmm, let's say your whole family (parents, grandparents, children etc) are watching movie together, what will make you more uncomfortable? Nudity or killing/death?

Comment: That's a good point! Nowadays, I can say that is 'nudity'. But if the situation was for real, what would make you more uncomfortable? Killing/death for sure. Is this any kind of morality deviation, bipolar morality? Is there any term for it?

Comment: @Joseph: Thanks for your interest. I study Law, so I have a basic knowledge of philosophy. But I'm writing a thesis (about law) that is related to virtual crimes and incidents. The answer to this question is something related to the behavior of people in this environment.
But, I've seen that there is no right or wrong answer to this, so, if there any way to follow, it would be nice.